# odoo8+pgpool2 ParseError: "Incorrect padding

Tags: base64, padding

i try to connect my odoo8 to my pgpool.

I write into the odoo-server.conf  corrects paramters to connect with my pgpool and it work fine..

but, when I create a new database trought odoo, it begins to create tables, index, .. but give me next error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 311, in _call_function
    return self.endpoint(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 705, in create
    request.session.authenticate(params['db_name'], 'admin', params['create_admin_pwd'])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 956, in authenticate
    uid = dispatch_rpc('common', 'authenticate', [db, login, password, env])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 115, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/service/common.py", line 26, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/service/common.py", line 37, in exp_authenticate
    res_users = openerp.registry(db)['res.users']
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/__init__.py", line 68, in registry
    return modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(database_name)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 339, in get
    update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 297, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, processed_modules = load_module_graph(cr, graph, status, perform_checks=update_module, report=report)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 900, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 986, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 852, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n, mode=mode)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 762, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data']._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1064, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 863, in create
    return super(users_view, self).create(cr, uid, values, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 661, in create
    user_id = super(users_implied, self).create(cr, uid, values, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 332, in create
    user_id = super(res_users, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 372, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 4093, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 4151, in _create
    self.pool[table].write(cr, user, [record_id], tocreate[table], context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 399, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py", line 564, in write
    result = super(res_partner, self).write(vals)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 3788, in write
    self._write(old_vals)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 592, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 4036, in _write
    cr, user, todo, fields_to_recompute, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 4409, in _store_set_values
    result = self._columns[val[0]].get(cr, self, ids, val, SUPERUSER_ID, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1460, in get
    result = self._fnct(obj, cr, uid, ids, name, self._arg, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 399, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py", line 191, in _get_image
    return dict((p.id, tools.image_get_resized_images(p.image)) for p in self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py", line 191, in <genexpr>
    return dict((p.id, tools.image_get_resized_images(p.image)) for p in self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/tools/image.py", line 223, in image_get_resized_images
    return_dict[medium_name] = image_resize_image_medium(base64_source, avoid_if_small=avoid_resize_medium)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/tools/image.py", line 161, in image_resize_image_medium
    return image_resize_image(base64_source, size, encoding, filetype, avoid_if_small)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/tools/image.py", line 70, in image_resize_image
    image_stream = StringIO.StringIO(base64_source.decode(encoding))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/base64_codec.py", line 42, in base64_decode
    output = base64.decodestring(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 321, in decodestring
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
ParseError: "Incorrect padding" while parsing /opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/base_data.xml:128, near
<record id="public_user" model="res.users">
            <field name="name">Public user</field>
            <field name="login">public</field>
            <field name="password"/>
            <!-- Avoid auto-including this demo user in any default group -->
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6,0,[ref('base.group_public')])]"/>
            <field name="image" type="base64" file="base/static/img/public_user-image.png"/>
            <field name="partner_id" ref="public_partner"/>
            <field name="active" eval="False"/>
        </record>
```

it creates some tables, index..., so it isn't a permissions error...

In odoo9 i have not this error and work fine ( but i need odoo8 version..)

thanks